# Prevent "→" from being written in URL alias

Tags: uri, path-aliases, caching

When the post title contains "→," it will be written in the URL alias.
When using Boost, an URL containing "→" will not be well cached; visitors will see the uncached node.

How do I prevent the "→" character from being written in URL aliases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [transliteration module](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration) does a good job on making ASCII urls and some other useful stuff. Works with path_auto.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the char(s) you don't want in the aliases in the "Strings to remove" textarea you find at /admin/config/search/path/settings (Drupal 7), or /admin/build/path/pathauto (Drupal 6).